# Power indices: Shapley and Banzhaf

Tags: game-theory

I've recently programmed the well-known cooperative game theory power indices, the one of Shapley and one of Banzhaf for my mobile phone and observed that they sometimes coincide.

Is there a natural necessary and sufficient condition for a $(0,1)-$normalized super-additive game of $n$ players when they coincide ? Several variations of this wanted condition would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I can only point out some specific cases where both indices coincide.

According to  [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221711006606?via%5C%3Dihub) Penrose (aka Banzhaf) and Shapley-Shubik power indices always rank the players in the same way. That makes it at least "more likely" for normalized Penrose and Shapley-Shubik indices to coincide.

For players $i=1,2,\dots,n$ let $N$ be the set of all players. A coalition $S$ is the subset of $N$ with all the yes-voters. Let $W\subseteq 2^N$ be the set of all winning coalitions and $\overline{W} = 2^N\setminus W$ the set of all losing coalitions.

For monotonic simple games we can formuate the power indices as follows.
\begin{align*}
  \beta_i &= 
  \sum\limits
  _{
    \substack{
      S \in \overline{W}:
      \\
       S\cup \{i\}\in W 
    } 
  }
  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
\\
  \phi_i &= 
  \sum\limits
  _{
    \substack{
      S\in \overline{W}:
    \\
      S\cup \{i\} \in W 
    } 
  }
  \frac{1}{\binom{n}{|S|}(n-|S|)}
\end{align*}
The Penrose index $\beta_i$ rewards every coaltion that can be turned from losing into winning by player $i$ with a constant amount, while the reward for Shapley-Shubik index $\phi_i$ depends on the coalition size.

Let's call $\{S\in \overline{W}: \exists i\in N: S\cup \{i\}\in W \}$ *relevant coalitions*. For normalized Penrose and Shapley-Shubik indices to coincide there is one easy case, which is if the Shapley-Shubik reward is the same for all relevant coalitions. This is the case if

- all relevant coalitions have the same size (this is trivial), or
- all relevant coalitions have only two different sizes $k,\ell$ and $n-k-1=\ell$.

The game $[4;3,2,2,1]$ for example has only relevant coalitions of size 1 and 2, namely $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}$. So $4-1-1 = 2$ and they conincide.

It would be nice to know if there are other cases where they conincide or to prove that there are no others. With increasing $n$ and many distinct weights it becomes unlikely that they conincide due to different rewards. As of now, I would see other examples as pure coincidence...